# ¿Como cambiar el formato de una tabla en pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

tengo el siguiente problema, he sido capaz de conseguir una tabla con los datos deseados pero el formato con el que la obtengo hace que no me deje hacer un plot adecuado. Antes ya había conseguido sacar la tabla en el formato que deseo pero de manera manual contando los elementos uno a uno, cosa que me parecía muy poco óptima. Los datos que he conseguido creo que son los mismos pero la tabla me aparece en un formato que no se corregir. El código que tengo es el siguiente.

```py
f = ['2019-12-20', '2020-01-20', '2018-06-06', '2018-12-07', '2018-10-05', '2018-08-20', '2017-01-19', '2019-02-27', '2019-08-28', '2018-05-11', '2018-03-14', '2018-04-09', '2019-01-30', '2020-01-27', '2019-01-22', '2017-11-23', '2018-03-02', '2018-09-26', '2017-05-25', '2019-04-11', '2019-09-16', '2018-04-23', '2018-10-04', '2018-11-16', '2017-09-25', '2018-12-28', '2018-12-24', '2018-01-30', '2019-06-25', '2018-08-08', '2018-03-26', '2019-11-06', '2019-02-04', '2018-12-14', '2018-02-09', '2018-03-27', '2019-02-25', '2019-07-19', '2019-09-19', '2019-03-01', '2017-01-17', '2018-05-02', '2018-04-09', '2019-11-04', '2017-01-17', '2019-11-19', '2018-12-07', '2017-10-03', '2018-02-01', '2017-02-07']
data = pd.DataFrame({'fecha':f})
fechas = pd.to_datetime( data['fecha'] , format = '%Y/%m/%d')
years = list(fechas.dt.year)
months = list(fechas.dt.month)
dates = pd.DataFrame({'year':years,'month':months})
tabla = dates.groupby(['year','month']).size().reset_index(name = 'total')
```

El original tiene muchas más fechas, pero con este puede hacerse una idea del objetivo aunque falte algún mes, pretendo contar el acumulado de frecuencias por esas fechas. El formato de tabla que busco es este:

```
      2017   2018   2019   2020
Ene  4593   9805  12237  10977
Feb  3348  10648   8307      0
Mar  3395   9652   7249      0
Abr  1719   7235   6905      0
May  1665   5759   5315      0
Jun  1663   4750   4347      0
Jul  1575   5095   4875      0
Ago  1665   4827   4305      0
Sep  2203   4920   5493      0
Oct  2423   8783   8397      0
Nov  3804   9136   8699      0
Dic  4713  10017   9742      0
```

Que el nombre de los meses se indique en ese formato es indiferente ya que seria solo sustituir el numero dentro de ese índice y en este caso lo he hecho yo manualmente. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de tu columna de tipo `datetime`, puedes simplemente agrupar por mes primero y por año después y aplicar `count`. Solo queda desapilar el `MultiIndex`, y renombrar los meses:

```
import pandas as pd

f = ['2019-12-20', '2020-01-20', '2018-06-06', '2018-12-07', '2018-10-05',
     '2018-08-20', '2017-01-19', '2019-02-27', '2019-08-28', '2018-05-11',
     '2018-03-14', '2018-04-09', '2019-01-30', '2020-01-27', '2019-01-22',
     '2017-11-23', '2018-03-02', '2018-09-26', '2017-05-25', '2019-04-11',
     '2019-09-16', '2018-04-23', '2018-10-04', '2018-11-16', '2017-09-25',
     '2018-12-28', '2018-12-24', '2018-01-30', '2019-06-25', '2018-08-08',
     '2018-03-26', '2019-11-06', '2019-02-04', '2018-12-14', '2018-02-09',
     '2018-03-27', '2019-02-25', '2019-07-19', '2019-09-19', '2019-03-01',
     '2017-01-17', '2018-05-02', '2018-04-09', '2019-11-04', '2017-01-17',
     '2019-11-19', '2018-12-07', '2017-10-03', '2018-02-01', '2017-02-07']

data = pd.DataFrame({'fecha': f})
data.fecha = pd.to_datetime(data.fecha, format='%Y/%m/%d')

data = (data.groupby([data.fecha.dt.month.rename(None),
                      data.fecha.dt.year.rename(None)])
            .count()
            .unstack()
            .fillna(0)
            .astype(int)
            )
data.rename(
    {1: "Ene", 2: "Feb", 3: "Mar", 4: "Abr", 5: "May", 6: "Jun", 
     7: "Jul", 8: "Ago", 9: "Sep", 10: "Oct", 11: "Nov", 12: "Dic"},
    inplace=True
    )
data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(0)
```

> ```
> >>> data
>
>      2017  2018  2019  2020
> Ene     3     1     2     2
> Feb     1     2     3     0
> Mar     0     4     1     0
> Abr     0     3     1     0
> May     1     2     0     0
> Jun     0     1     1     0
> Jul     0     0     1     0
> Ago     0     2     1     0
> Sep     1     1     2     0
> Oct     1     2     0     0
> Nov     1     1     3     0
> Dic     0     5     1     0
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que buscaba justamente, no tenia conocimiento de la existencia del comando unstack(), ha habido otros casos en los que debería haberlo usado y no lo hice por esto mismo. Muchas gracias de nuevo, me ha sido de gran ayuda.